# PHP XPath: evaluate query result as an Integer

Tags: php, xml, xpath

writing this:

```
$likes = $xpath->query('//span[@class="LikesCount"]');
```

this is waht I get:

```
155 like
```

**I would like to write the query so that number_before_like > 5**

```
$likes = $xpath->query('

((int)substring-before(//span[@class="LikesCount"], " ")) > 5


');
```

Follows the markup:

```
<div class="pin">

[...]

<a href="/pin/56787645270909880/" class="PinImage ImgLink">
    <img src="http://media-cache-ec3.pinterest.com/upload/56787645270909880_d7AaHYHA_b.jpg" alt="Krizia" data-componenttype="MODAL_PIN" class="PinImageImg" style="height: 288px;">
</a>

<p class="stats colorless">
    <span class="LikesCount"> 
        2 likes 
    </span>
    <span class="RepinsCount">
        6 repins
    </span>
</p>

[...]

</div>
```

Comment: what does the markup look like?

Comment: added the markup, I'm stuck since 8 hours on this O_o

Comment: the easiest way would be to wrap the number in another span. Then you could just select `.LikesCount` where child span has text value > 5.  If you can't change the markup, then you'll need a regex that captures the first number(s) in the text node.

Comment: Have you try `$likes = $xpath->evaluate('

((int)substring-before(//span[@class="LikesCount"], " ")) > 5


');`

Comment: check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2994336/128245

Comment: I think I will use getelementbyid and stuff, this kind of parsing looks too complicated for my level :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with XPath syntax alone, by making sure that extraneous whitespace is taken out of the picture.

```
$query = 'number(substring-before(normalize-space(
          //span[@class="LikesCount" 
          and substring-before(normalize-space(.), " ") > 5]), " "))';

$likes = $xpath->evaluate($query);
```

Alternatively, let PHP do the hard work for you.

```
$query = 'number(php:functionString("intval",
          //span[@class="LikesCount"
          and php:functionString("intval", .) > 5]))';

$xpath->registerNamespace('php', 'http://php.net/xpath');
$xpath->registerPHPFunctions("intval");
$likes = $xpath->evaluate($query);
```

If you're going to start asking PHP to do some of the work, it might well just be easier to use a simple query and filter the results as you need.

```
foreach ($xpath->query('//span[@class="LikesCount"]') as $span) {
    $int = (int) $span->nodeValue;
    if ($int > 5) {
        echo $int;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you salathe, how do I print the value? When I write echo $likes->item(0)->textContent."<br />"; I get this error: Call to a member function item() on a non-object

Comment: How to print the entire results? I mean in my markup there are at least 20 entries and in this way it just shows me one

Comment: By asking the right question from the start. The simplest is to take the `foreach` loop I've already shown you.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that your issue is actually the extra spaces in your selected `<span>`. Try stripping them out. For example, you could use [`normalize-space()`](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_functions.asp#string):

```
substring-before(normalize-space(//span[@class="LikesCount"]), " ")
```

The like count string will be [converted to a double](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#numbers) by the XPath processor before execution of the greater than operator. (You can force this conversion via [number()](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-number), but it is unnecessary in this case, and would likely fail for the same reason the auto-convert failed - leading whitespace.)

Comment: Thank you Mark, the problem is that I don't seem to be able to strip the number out of that string either