# Get exact word from param using XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I'm trying to select some text from a parameter and place it into a variable, this variable just has plain text.

```
<xsl:variable name="Underline">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="contains($style-name, 'u')">true</xsl:when>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
```

The value of this parameter (*$style-name*) can be anything from or combination of **strike, em, u, strong, sub, and sup.**

`$style-name: "strike em u sub"`

The problem is when I use the above code it also thinks that **sub** and **u** are the same because it finds the character u. This is the nature of contains.

*I did some research here:*

[http://www.w3.org XPATH](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#section-String-Functions)

[XPath to return only elements containing the text, and not its parents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2994198/xpath-to-return-only-elements-containing-the-text-and-not-its-parents)

But I can't find anything that works for me. If you need further information, let me know.

This is also XSLT 1.0 only. I'm using Visual Studio 2012, I'm not 100% sure what the engine is.

I can provide the input, but it's out of the scope of the issue, its just a sub-problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This actually doesn't require tokenizing. It should be as simple as this:

```
<xsl:variable name="Underline">
  <xsl:if test="contains(concat(' ',$style-name,' '),' u ')">true</xsl:if>
</xsl:variable>
```

or maybe even better

```
<xsl:variable name="Underline">
  <xsl:if test="contains(concat(' ',normalize-space($style-name),' '),' u ')">true</xsl:if>
</xsl:variable>
```

That is, if it's guaranteed that you have a space separated list.

Answer (score 4):

**XSLT 2.0 Solution**

Break into a sequence of tokens and compare using `=`:

```
<xsl:when test="tokenize($style-name,' ') = 'u')">true</xsl:when>
```

This will convert all of the space-delimited tokens into a sequence, and `= 'u'` will match if any of the tokens match 'u'.

**XSLT 1.1 Solution**

```
<xsl:template name="tokenize">
  <xsl:param name="token" />
  <xsl:param name="text"/>
  <xsl:if test="string-length($text)">
     <token><xsl:value-of select="substring-before(concat($text,$token),$token)"/></token>
     <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
       <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text,$token)"/>
       <xsl:with-param name="token" select="$token"/>
     </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

...

<xsl:variable name="tokens">
  <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
     <xsl:with-param name="text" select="$style-name"/>
     <xsl:with-param name="token" select="' '"/>
  </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:when test="$tokens/token = 'u'">true</xsl:when>
```

**XSLT 1.0 Solution**

Requires an extension that's included in every major XSL processor (including MSXSL). Add this namespace declaration to your stylesheet:

```
xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
```

And change the @test:

```
<xsl:when test="msxsl:node-set($tokens)/token = 'u'">true</xsl:when>
```

For ESLT-aware processors (Saxon, xsltproc, Xalan-J, jd.xslt, and 4XSLT) use `xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"` and `exsl:node-set()`. For Xalan-C use `xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xalan"` and `xalan:nodeset()`.