# Select only elements who directly contain text

Tags: jquery

So I have something like this:

```
<div class="main">
  <div class="useless">
    text I don't want.    
  </div>
  <div class="useless">
    text I don't want.    
  </div>
  <div class="narrow">
    text I'm searching for
  </div>
  <div class="useless">
    text I don't want.    
  </div>
  <div class="useless">
    text I don't want.    
  </div>
</div>
```

Using jQuery's lovely [`:contains` selector](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/), I can search for a keyword, but it will return both the parent and the child.

I'd like it to only return elements who directly contain the word for which I'm searching.

Stackoverflow usefully suggested [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7896455/jquery-selector-for-an-element-that-directly-contains-text) as a previous attempt, but it seems extremely clunky since it's crawling all dom nodes and requires a lot of unclear code.

Comment: Flagging this as a dupe of the question you've referenced; while I appreciate that you're not satisfied with the answers there, for reasons that you've given, it is still the same question and you haven't given any specific requirements not given in the other question. The appropriate course of action would probably be to place a bounty on that question, if/once you're able to do so. I'm still curious about this and looking into it, though.

Comment: *"it seems extremely clunky since it's crawling all dom nodes"*. That's what you have to do in any case. You could also select all nodes at once with `$('*')` and then iterate over them, but in any case, you have to traverse all nodes.

Comment: Probably, you need a more advanced selector like [jQuery XPath plugin](https://github.com/ilinsky/jquery-xpath). If you decide to use xpath, maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2994336/771578) will help you too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This script will find all nodes that contain a specific text.  It will also allow you to do any string tests on the text (regex etc).

```
function getNodesThatContain(text) {
    var textNodes = $(document).find(":not(iframe, script, style)")
      .contents().filter( 
          function() {
           return this.nodeType == 3 
             && this.textContent.indexOf(text) > -1;
    });
    return textNodes.parent();
};

console.log(getNodesThatContain("test"));
```

Here is a fiddle for testing: http://jsfiddle.net/85qEh/4/

PS - For increased speed use a different top level selector. For example if you only need inside #container then you would `var textNodes = $('#container')...`

Comment: Certainly more readable and succinct than bobince's solution. +1. Not sure how the performance will compare, though, which may matter.

Comment: Just tested it with the example you showed http://jsfiddle.net/85qEh/3/  Looks like Jquery de-dupes the result set for you.

Comment: Yeah, I tried just now and found the same thing - my mistake. Also, sorry, already edited the point out of my comment after realizing I was in error and it's too late for me to edit it back in now, so your comment looks like you're replying to nobody. Sorry. :P

Comment: Did a quick performance test, my code is faster than the other code provided if you extend the other code to look for div, span, and a tags instaed of just div.  The just div method is fastest.

Comment: You could add `style` to the `find(":not(iframe, script, style)")`. I had some hits there as well.

Comment: **caseINsensitive solution:** use [.toLowercase()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) to match text _caseinsensitive_. I augmented the code as thus: `&& this.textContent.toLowerCase().indexOf(text.toLowerCase()) > -1`

Answer (score 2):

The solution, which is provided in the other question as referenced above but as a not highly regarded solution apparently, is to do this:

```
$("div:contains('searching')").filter(function() {
    return (
    $(this).clone() //clone the element
    .children() //select all the children
    .remove() //remove all the children
    .end() //again go back to selected element
    .filter(":contains('searching')").length > 0)
}).css('border', 'solid 1px black');
```

I'd add it's less clunky than writing a huge thing to crawl all DOM nodes, and really should affect less places when narrowly scoped.

If anyone else has better ideas, I'm definitely interested.

http://jsfiddle.net/TT7dR/42/

Comment: It's hacky and inefficient, but it looks like it'll work (and the comments clearly explain the logic behind it). A tentative +1, but *surely* there's a shorter and cleaner way?

Comment: But here other's divs are bordered too.

Comment: JSFiddle fail. I accidently used the previous link which contained poor markup and didn't directly relate to the question. I updated it, and it now provides better insight.

Comment: Sadly, this would be the way I approached this. I feel the same way as you though, @RandallB, there *must* be a better way...

Comment: If the answer is from the other question, then why copy it? Just provide a comment and flag the question as duplicate if you can. I hope you upvoted the other answer at least.

Answer (score -2):

Try This In JS

```
$('div >:contains("text Im searching for")')
```

Comment: The downvote is not mine, but note this is part of the "clunky" solutions available in the linked question.

Comment: And more to the point, it doesn't work, as explained in comments on the other question. -1

Comment: The issue that others have discovered: http://jsfiddle.net/DM4vz/2/ If you add a parent above this, the search will fail.