# How can I edit the body class of this website?

Tags: html, web, inspect-element

I would like to change the **body class=""** of a website, in this case it's WhatsApp Web, if you go to inspect element and change **body class="web"** to **body class="web dark"** the page becomes dark. How can I save this so I don't have to do this every time I load the page? Thanks!

Comment: I'm assuming you can't modify the code directly? What kind of browser are you using, Chrome?

Comment: Yes. I just want to not have to change the code every time I load the page, so the web stays dark all the time.

Comment: Try using `greasemonkey` or `tampermonkey`. BTW, be prepared to get your question downvoted or closed as it is to generic and not within 'SO rules'. [reprex]

Answer (score 0):

You'll likely need to use a Chrome Extension for this. Here is a helpful link to a [similar use-case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34467627/change-dom-content-with-chrome-extension) where the person was attempting to create their own extension, if you're interested in creating your own solution. Here's a reference from the Google Chrome team on [creating your own Chrome extension](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts).

If you're looking for something a little more out-of-the-box, check out this [Chrome Plugin, Page Manipulator](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/page-manipulator/mdhellggnoabbnnchkeniomkpghbekko?hl=en). There are several other plugins such as [TaperMonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en).

The idea is to have some extension in Chrome that will automatically apply the changes you attempting to do directly to the DOM of the page.

Answer (score 0):

what you are trying to do is not possible because each time you reload the page the code will get updated(By updated i mean the orignal code).

But there is a way you can do the same by creating your own **add-ons in mozilla or extensions for chrome** what this extension will do is **whenever they will see a "tag" or "class" matching the constraint will get replace by the value you want.**

like in your case from "web" to "web dark".