# Using a python variable in xPath selector in scrapy

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I want to choose the elements that their `text` contains `bar`. I have a python variable named `foo` that it's value is `"bar"` and I want to use it like this:

```
foo = "bar"
response.xpath('//*[contains(text(), foo)]')
```

But it returns all the elements! What is the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you try:

```
foo = "bar"
response.xpath('//*[contains(text(), "'+foo+'")]')
```

?

This is a combination of Mathiou's answer and a correct XPath expression for `contains`. Do not forget that you are dealing with a string even in the XPath expression and you have to tell it that you have a string.

Comment: Yep, this is what I corrected as mentionned in the comments :)

Answer (score 4):

## First

regarding your question:

> But it returns all the elements! What is the problem?

your xpath-query returns "all" elements because xpath cannot recognize your "foo" within the string (`'//*[contains(text(), foo)]'`) as a valid variable, so it returns **an empty node-set** instead -> this means that it kind of checks what elements contain an empty string, and that is basically all elements =)

## Solution

use double quotes and single quotes to your advantage like this:

```
foo = "bar"
response.xpath("//*[contains(text(), '" + foo + "')]")
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this :

```
foo = "bar"
response.xpath('//*[contains(text(), \''+foo+'\')]')
```

?

Comment: it returns all the elements again!

Comment: If it is a problem in the xpath expression, you might want to have a look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2994198/xpath-to-return-only-elements-containing-the-text-and-not-its-parents

Comment: Maybe using the `'` before and after your string ?

Comment: But why escape the `'` when you can use both if you need some alternative? ;)