# xpath search for class and text - combine two xpath selector

Tags: xpath

I know there are tousands of simple question about xpath but i dont get it how to combine two not too simple expressions...

My xml structure:

```
<div class="some-container">
    <div class="btn  btn-blue">
        <div class="btn-text"><!-- Select by class -->
            <span> <!-- Select by text-->
                Download
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

**Select by class**

I know achieved to select the div by searching after the class:

```
//*/div[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' btn-text')]
```

---

**Select by text**

To select also the span i know i can simply add `/span` but then i want to select by text. 
For that usecase i got the xpath ([form here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2994336)):

```
//*/text()[normalize-space(.)='Download']/parent::*
```

---

Those selector both are working properly but i want to combine them

1. Search for class "btn"
2. Search for text inside span that exactly matches

I tried to concat like that but that dont work [test-example](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/48f08aa3038aecfb38e99f2ba5911543):

```
//div[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' btn-text')]/text()[normalize-space(.)='Download']/parent::*
```

even if it'd work there is no selecting by span tag

Anyone who could help?

Comment: `//div[@class = 'btn-text']/span[text()='Download']`?

Answer (score 1):

Your XPath is looking for a text node directly inside the `div`, but the text node you're looking for is inside a `span`. That's why it's not succeeding.

To get it to work, just change the XPath to look for the `span` and not the text node:

```
//div[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' btn-text ')]/span[normalize-space(.)='Download']
```