# Highlighting Exact Text Match

Tags: javascript, jquery, userscripts

I have the following java userscript:

```
function highlightWord(word) {
var xpath = "//text()[contains(., '" + word + "')]";
var texts = document.evaluate(xpath, document.body, null, XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);
for (n = 0; n < texts.snapshotLength; n++) {
    var textNode = texts.snapshotItem(n);
    var p = textNode.parentNode;
    var a = [];
    var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
    textNode.nodeValue.split(word).forEach(function(text, i) {
        var node;
        if (i) {
            node = document.createElement('span');
            node.style.backgroundColor = 'lightgreen';
            node.appendChild(document.createTextNode(word));
            frag.appendChild(node);
        }
        if (text.length) {
            frag.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
        }
        return a;
    });
    p.replaceChild(frag, textNode);
    }
}
highlightWord('office');
```

Would anyone be able to help me with finding a solution to only match the exact text of the highlightWord's that I add? For example, I want it to only match "office" and not "officer".

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2994336/2707021

should help. Essentially you need to apply word boundaries to the pattern match string on this line

```
var xpath = "//text()[contains(., '" + word + "')]";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the following line of your code

```
textNode.nodeValue.split(word).forEach(function(text, i) {
```

into the one shown below. This will highlight, only the word that you mention.

```
textNode.nodeValue.split(RegExp("\\b" + word + "\\b")).forEach(function (text, i) {
```

The XPath just extracts the entire text, the actual string search in your code happens in the above statement.