# Choose XPATH based on <th> string value with selenium

Tags: python, selenium

There is a table that I want to get the XPATH of, however the amount of rows and columns is inconsistent across results so I can't just right click and get copy the full XPATH.

My current code:

```
result_priority_number = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div/div[2]/div[6]/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[18]/td[2]")
```

The table header names though are always consistent. How do I get the value of an element where the table header specifically says something (i.e. "Priority Number")

Comment: Where is your HTML?

Comment: Can you share a link to that page?

Comment: https://register.epo.org/application?number=EP11010067 With different patents the amount of rows displayed can be inconsistent, so I need a way to consistently get "Priority Number" and such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can't just right click and get copy the full XPATH.

Never use this method. Xpath has a very useful feature for search! It isn't just for nested pathing!

```
//td[contains(text(),'header value')]
```

or if it has many tables and you want only one of its:

```
//table[@id='id_of_table']//td[contains(text(),'header value')]
```

or the table hasn't id or class:

```
//table[2]//td[contains(text(),'header value')]
```

where 2 is index of table in page

and other many feature for searching in html nodes

in your case, for get **Filing language**:

```
//td[contains(text(),'Filing language')]/following-sibling::td
```

Comment: Thank you, it's my first time encountering python and XPATH as well, watched 1 video and freestyled the rest. Submitting as answer

Comment: @dennis , read more: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56971704/4650634 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/2994336/4650634

Comment: @dennis in your case `//td[contains(text(),'Priority number')]/following-sibling::td` and `//td[contains(text(),'Priority number')]/parent::tr/following-sibling::tr[1]//td` and `//td[contains(text(),'Priority number')]/parent::tr/following-sibling::tr[2]//td`

Comment: @dennis You can test xpath with google chrome inspect element, open it and press `ctrl+f`  and paste xpath query in search box